# Iterate over has_many through relationship and include data from joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, iteration, has-many-through

I have a very simple rails app with three models: Recipes, Ingredients, and a joining table Quantities that stores the amount of each ingredient in the recipe. For one recipe, I want to list all the associate ingredients and the amount found in the joining table.  How do I iterate over the ingredients, but also include the data from the quantities table?

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :quantities
    has_many :ingredients, through: :quantities
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and:

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :quantities
    has_many :recipes, through: :quantities
end
```

and finally joining table:

```
class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :recipe
    belongs_to :ingredient
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient, allow_destroy: true
end
```

It seems like it should be really easy to do this iteration but I am not sure how.

show.html.erb:

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <% #I know the line below is wrong, but not sure how
    # to iterate over the ingredients for the recipe and
    # include the amount field from the quantities table
    # as well as the ingredient name. %>
    <li><%= ingredient.amount ingredient.name  %></li>
<% end %>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller's action do something like this:

```
@recipe = Recipe.includes(:ingredients, :quantities).find(params[:id]) # avoid N+1
```

and then, in your view:

```
<% @recipe.quantities.each do |quantity| %>
  <%= quantity.ingredient.name %> - 
  <%= quantity.amount %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The join table `quantities` is likely to have one one row for a combination of `recipe` and `ingredient`, even though the `has_many :through` implementation allows for multiple rows.

This allows for accessing the ingredient quantity and name as follows:

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
  <li>
    <%= ingredient.quantities.first.amount %>
    <%= ingredient.name  %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```